# Programmatically upload an image to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to programmatically upload images to the media library by taking an ACF url, running it through the Wordpress function and then updating a taxonomy field.

I know for a fact that `$icon` is the correct URL and the `update_field` function is correct.

The part that is going wrong is the upload image part. I think I've followed the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image) correctly but no image is uploaded into the library and nothing is connected to the ACF field on the taxonomy.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    // Icon
    $icon = get_field('icon', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
    $field_key = "field_5ad5e7e5e295c";

    if($icon != "") {
      // The ID of the post this attachment is for.
      $return = "id";

      // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

      // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
      $attach_id = media_sideload_image($icon, $post_id, $desc, id);


      update_field( $field_key, $attach_id, $taxonomy.'_'.$french );
      update_field( $field_key, $attach_id, $taxonomy.'_'.$german );
      update_field( $field_key, $attach_id, $taxonomy.'_'.$italian );
      update_field( $field_key, $attach_id, $taxonomy.'_'.$russian );
      update_field( $field_key, $attach_id, $taxonomy.'_'.$spanish );
    }
```

Comment: what's going wrong? is there any attached error? Also, I personally prefer to just use vanilla PHP to upload to a directory. WP I find to be ... buggy

Comment: what's the value of `$attach_id`?

Comment: @treyBake _“Also, I personally prefer to just use vanilla PHP to upload to a directory”_ - but a mere upload to the directory in the file system is not what is needed here, that alone doesn’t create a proper, usable media library entry. Those are technically posts (same as pretty much everything else), so additional meta data is stored in the database.

Comment: @04FS but it isn't hard to re-create the functionality (insert-side)

Comment: @treyBake depending on what other plugins might be hooking into the process, it might be … of course you can implement your own solution that takes care of executing all hooks and filters properly as well - but then you’re really just re-programming the whole already existing functionality.

Comment: @04FS tis a valid point .. in my xp with wp, I've just found their functions to be problems rather than solutions - the whole echo instead of return really gets my goat (not an actual problem per say, but a morality issue for sure)

Comment: One thing to check, on your `update_field()` function - the variables for `$french`, `$german`, `$italian`, `$russian`, `$spanish` must represent a term ID. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found a really simple way around... it doesn't solve my question as such as I've approached it a different way.

The url of the media item obviously already exists in the media library. Therefore I just need the item id of it by looking via the url.

```
    // Icon
    $icon = get_field('icon', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
    $field_key = "field_5ad5e7e5e295c";

    if($icon != "") {

      $item = attachment_url_to_postid( $icon );

      update_field( $field_key, $item, $taxonomy.'_'.$french );
      update_field( $field_key, $item, $taxonomy.'_'.$german );
      update_field( $field_key, $item, $taxonomy.'_'.$italian );
      update_field( $field_key, $item, $taxonomy.'_'.$russian );
      update_field( $field_key, $item, $taxonomy.'_'.$spanish );
    }
```